# Initializing a new class in its own constructor

Tags: c#, properties, class-design

I have a User class. One of the properties needs to be an "associated" user, so it's type needs to be User. Right now when I initialize the class, I get a stack overflow when it tries to initialize the Associated property. Current code:

```
public class User {
    public User() {
        this.Associated = new User();
    }

    public User Associated { get; set; }
}
```

Is this doable or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Why can't null be a valid default value for your Associated user ?

Comment: There are other default values in the associated User class that I need, even for an unassociated User.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a lazy loaded method for your aggregated `User` class and not initialize it in the constructor:

```
public class User {
    private User _user;

    public User Associated 
    { 
        get
        {
            if (_user == null)
                _user = new User();
            return _user;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Does User.Associated have to be populated on construction? If you remove the assignment from the constructor you shouldn't get SO.

The reason you are getting an SO is because when you construct a `User()` it constructs a `User()` which in turn constructs a `User()` and it is turtles all the way down.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the `User` constructor recursively. Every time you `new` a `User`, it `new`s another `User` ad infinitum (or rather, ad `StackOverflowException`).

Answer (score 1):

Do not initialize the Associated member in the constructor.  If you only initialize it when you need it, I think the stack overflow should go away.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've developed an endless loop of new users. Each new user gets a new user as an associate.

I would remove the assignement from the default constructor, then add it as a public property. Doing this will allow you to control when associates are assigned, and will prevent the endless loop.

Answer (score 1):

Calling the constructor inside the constructor leads you to an infinite loop:

Create a new `User` instance -> Create a new `User` instance -> Create a new `User` instance -> Create a new `User` instance -> Create a new `User` instance -> Create a new `User` instance...

You could do something like that:

```
public class User {
    public User() {

    }

    public AddAssociatedUser() {
        this.Associated = new User();
    }

    public User Associated { get; set; }
}
```

And call the `AddAssociatedUser` when you need it.